# Is there any way to insert control by order In Designer.cs in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

i made a two button control, but when i saw Designer.cs file, the controls were inserted like this:

[this is the captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbhkQ.png)

i think this is a problem cause this.Controls list save items by reverse order.

so.. is there any way to save items by order?

Comment: Why does the insertion order matter to you?

Comment: What you are showing is text, please paste it into your question as text, `formatted as code`. I believe the designer places the controls on the form in reverse _Z-Order_ (i.e., the _topmost_ control last, so it's on top of the pile). Why does this upset you, generally what you care about is the _tab order_, and that easily adjustable

Comment: You can modify designer file yourself if you wish, but that would change nothing, post your real problem, not just your suggestions

Comment: [View > Other Windows > Document Outline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#document-outline-window)

Comment: *I think this is a problem* > No, it's expected behavior and works as expected at run-time and design time. But if you would like to change the z-order of the control at design time, you can use *Document Outline* window. You can also use *SendToBack* and *BringToFront* commands from context menu or *Layout* toolbar.

Comment: You'd also be well advised to give any of your controls *meaningful names* rather than leaving them as `button1`, `button2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only time this would matter is if you were placing two controls on top of each other. Even then though, the order in the Designer file wouldn't matter as long as you update your `Z-index` and `Visibility` correctly.

If it really bothers you, you can update the designer file manually, but I try to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: When the order - or the whole way how the designer.cs changes - really matters is when merging multiple developer branches. I have had pleasure to work on two winforms legacy projects recently and it is pain. Designer may move the code blocks around on slightest touch. Yes, I know it is as designed, but heck...